# ffmpeg produce not expected number of frames

Tags: video, image-processing, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm using this command to count frames in video.

```
FRAME_COUNT=`./ffprobe -v error -count_frames -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 $VIDEO_NAME`
```

and this command for video splitting:

```
ffmpeg -i $VIDEO_NAME -qscale:v 1 $DIRNAME$SEPARATOR'image%d.jpg'
```

but last command produce much more images then expected for some videos, for example calculated number of frames is 597 and produces number of images > 100,000.

What can be the case of such behaviour?

Comment: if you are using these scripts I take it you fully understand them - if you dont understand them dont use them. why should the video be 597 frames? is that true according to you? is it a movie or a video more than an hour?

Comment: @gpasch As I understand number of frames is number of images can be produced from video without dropping any parts of it. And  `-count_frames ` as described in help `count the number of frames per stream`.

Comment: just do an ffmpeg -i thisvideo.mp4 and post the output in your question